# Can't get index from a 2d array

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get 25 Numbers to put them in a 2D list/array but whenever i try to get the index of the item, I'm always facing a valueError.

**What i tried.**

I have tried using a for loop with the enumerate() function to get the specfic Item which is (1).

I have also tried using the .index() method but also with that I was faced with a ValueError: 1 is not in the list. Which made me confused as to why the code isn't working.

```
mylist = [list(map(int, input().split())),
                  list(map(int, input().split())),
                  list(map(int, input().split())),
                  list(map(int, input().split())),
                  list(map(int, input().split())),]
print(mylist)
print(mylist.index(1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach to consider:

```
myList = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [12, 3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 3, 6, 2]]

def index_2d(input_list, value):
    for i, row in enumerate(input_list):
        try:
            return (i, row.index(value))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    # You can also raise ValueError here instead of implicit return (un-comment the next line)
    # raise ValueError(f'{value} is not in the list')
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print(myList)
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [12, 3, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 4, 3, 6, 2]]

>>> print(index_2d(myList, 12))
(2, 0)

>>> print(index_2d(myList, 11))
None
```

**Explanation:**

We accept the 2d-list and a value we are trying to check. Then use `enumerate` (to keep track of the index of the main array). We then use `index()` at each row (list in the main array) to check if the value belongs there, if not (`ValueError` exception got raised) we simply move to the next row and repeat. But if `index()` resolves, we return a tuple of the index of the list inside the main list (from the `enumerate()`) and the index inside the second list or row.